# The setLong method arguments are mismatching with datatype

Tags: java

The following code:

```
 public int getCount(long user_id){

    Query q = getSession().createQuery("select count(Items) from User_detail as U where U.user_id = :user_id ");

    q.setLong(user_id, user_id);

    int ItemCount =((Long)q.uniqueResult()).intValue(); 

    return ItemCount;
}
```

complains that

> The method setLong(int, long) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (long,long).

Comment: Where is user_id defined?

Answer (score 2):

In the method `setLong(int, long)`, the first parameter (int) is the index of the param in your query, not the param itself. So you must do:

```
q.setLong(1, user_id);
```

Alternatively you can use the name of the param, so you can also do:

```
q.setLong("user_id", user_id);
```

By this second way, the first param is a `String` instead of an `int`

Answer (score 0):

**The method setLong() aceepts** 
`setLong(int position, long val)`

**so I guess You should modify it to**

```
setLong(1, user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

change that to

```
q.setLong("user_id", user_id);
```

You have used the parameter  **:user_id** as the key in the Query. So you must specify the same name and the value for it as the argument for the function `setLong(String, value)`.